# Removing Rogue SSL Certs on AWS

Tags: apache, amazon-web-services, https, ssl-certificate, elastic-load-balancer

I have a client site set up on AWS with multiple servers running HTPPS behind an Elastic Load Balancer. At some point, someone from the client's team attempted to update the SSL Cert by installing a new one directly on one of the servers (instead of in the ELB).

I was able to upload a new cert to the ELB, but when traffic is directed towards the server with the improperly installed cert, it triggers a security warning.

No one can seem to answer who attempted this install, how they went about, or where they installed it.

What's the best way to go about finding and removing it?

Thanks,

ty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's installed on the server, it has very little to do with AWS. I see you tagged the question with [apache](/questions/tagged/apache) so I assume the server is running Apache Web Server. You will have to connect into that server and remove the SSL settings from the Apache Web Server configuration, just like you would with an Apache Web Server install anywhere else.